# Replacing emojis with textclean won't fully working for me in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert the emojis contained in a twitter dataset into words. I am using the "textclean" package in R, but when using replace_emoji, some emojies are replaced by the corresponding words and others are shown in a other format

```
df_test$tweet <- textclean::replace_emoji(df_test$tweet)
```

My expected output for e.g. " STARSHARKS OVERVIEW " would be something like :

```
shark STARSHARKS OVERVIEW shark
```

instead I get:

```
<f0><9f><a6><88> STARSHARKS OVERVIEW <f0><9f><a6><88>
```

Another problem I encounter is that even apostrophes are replaced by the aforementioned format.

It seems somewhat weird to me because some of the emojis are actually replaced correctly.

I would be thankfull for any help as I am quite new to coding in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the shark emoji is not in the `lexicon::hash_emojis` data table. As such, you need to define your own `data.table` with these emojis.

```r
test = " STARSHARKS OVERVIEW "

custom_emoji_dt = data.table::data.table(x = "<f0><9f><a6><88>", y = "shark")

textclean::replace_emoji(test, emoji_dt = custom_emoji_dt)
#> [1] "shark STARSHARKS OVERVIEW shark "
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is the correct answer, but you will probably want to add the shark emoji to the list that lexicon (what textclean uses to ID emojis) uses. This allows you to use the `replace_emoji` function as is with your new emoji inserted. Taking mhovd code, it would be something like `hash_update <- lexicon::hash_emojis` then `hash_update <- rbind(hash_update, custom_emoji_dt)`

Comment: Okay, so I'll probably add the missing emojis to the list manually. Thanks for your help in understanding whats the problem and how i can solve it!